# Keep all section headers visible in a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, header

I've build a table view with a number of section around 5 or 6.

I define my table view style as "plain". So at any time it keep one header on the top.

But I would like to keep all of my header section visible at any time (I'm working for an iPad app, so I have enough place !).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own control; it can't be done with the standard UITableView.

Comment: OK thx. But where can I find some documentation to achieve that myself ? I have to extend the UITableView ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to accomplish this? I am running into the same problem.